# How to make a list of files whose names are stored in a tupple in same sequence

Tags: python, list, python-os

I am creating a list of files using `os` module in python, whose names I have stored in tupples.

I have tried it and its working but in the output of the list those files are stored in a list and it is not in same sequence as stored in tupple.

```
import os

files_to_open = ('hello.', 'how.', 'afraid.', 'are.', 'you.')

os.chdir(r"/home/usr/pro/files") #this is the file path in linux where i have stored those files

path = os.getcwd()

images = [fil for fil in os.listdir(path) 
              if img.startswith(files_to_open)]

print(images)
```

so I expected that the output list of images would be:

```
['hello.', 'how.', 'afraid.', 'are.', 'you.']
```

but I got

```
['how.', 'afraid.', 'hello.', 'you.']
```

Comment: Hi! What is `img` in the list comprehension?

Comment: You dont like order or the fact that there is no `are.`?

Comment: The code you show (assuming `img` is supposed to be `fil`) will create a list of filenames in whatever order they're read from the filesystem. That need not be the same order as your tuple. As for why you're missing the file with the `'are.'` prefix, the most likely reason is that no such file exists. Without knowing more about your filesystem's contents, we can't debug that for you.

Comment: hey I just realised there is an extra parenthesis in the list comprehension. I've submitted the edit. I've tried the code and works as expected with the edit so I think @Blckknght might be right. Hope that helps. 

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This code is very difficult for us to debug without knowing the directory contents and the value of `img`. Please make a [mre]. You can [edit] the question.